# How to change the Navigation View Style of a Navigation View depending on a @State in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, state, navigationview

I am currently working with `Navigation View` in `SwiftUI`.

**Problem:** I would like to change the `Navigation View Style` from an `Descendent View` using `@State & @Binding`.

```swift
@Binding var defaultNavigationStyle: Bool
    
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        sidebar
            
        Text("Choose an Option from the Sidebar.")
            
        Text("Select an Element.")
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(defaultNavigationStyle ? DefaultNavigationViewStyle() : StackNavigationViewStyle())
}
```

> **Obviously, this does not work** since the Elements have different Types. **Error Message:** *Result Values in '?:' expression have mismatching types 'DefaultNavigationViewStyle' and 'StackNavigationViewStyle'*

**Question:** How can I change the `Navigation View Style` using `@State & @Binding`, **without** creating a completely different NavigationView and loosing all the `State`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional modifier:

```
extension View {
    typealias ContentTransform<Content: View> = (Self) -> Content

    @ViewBuilder
    func conditionalModifier<TrueContent: View, FalseContent: View>(
        _ condition: Bool,
        ifTrue: ContentTransform<TrueContent>,
        ifFalse: ContentTransform<FalseContent>
    ) -> some View {
        if condition {
            ifTrue(self)
        } else {
            ifFalse(self)
        }
    }
}
```

and apply it to the `NavigationView`:

```
NavigationView {
    sidebar
    Text("Choose an Option from the Sidebar.")
    Text("Select an Element.")
}
.conditionalModifier(
    defaultNavigationStyle,
    ifTrue: { $0.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle()) },
    ifFalse: { $0.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) }
)
```